# .NET Framework Could not load file or assembly, but there's no reference to the assembly anywhere

Tags: asp.net

We've recently moved away from an old email client (Chilkat) in our .NET framework (4.7.2) project. Removed all references in code, then went into the nuget package manager and uninstalled the package. I've used an external tool to search for all occurrences of the word "chilkat" in the solution and there's nothing left. The project builds fine.

But when I navigate to my application in my browser, I get "Could not load file or assembly 'ChilkatDotNet45.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." This is after cleaning, rebuilding, deleting the .vs folder, restarting my computer, all multiple times. There's literally no reference to that dll anywhere, but something is still looking for it.

Anyone seen this before or have any ideas on what to do? I've been stuck on this for over a day and can't for the life of me think of what to do.

Stack trace, though I can't imagine it's helpful:
[image]

Comment: Are you making sure to search all the .csproj files as well? Some times the older .csproj format files will have required dependencies listed that may get removed in the other package dependency sources (like web.config), but not removed as requirements in the .csproj. I've seen this a lot of times when upgrading older .NET 4 projects that required BCL packages.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @EricMagers yes, it was removed from both the .csproj file as well as the packages.config. I've searched all files in the repo and there's no occurence of "chilkat" anywhere. It's almost certainly something that's in some way cached, but I just can't think of any other steps to take to reset that.